# Suggestion on table partitioning in POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, data-modeling, partitioning

I am designing 2 tables.

`user_table (userid username)` *100K records expected*

`transaction_table(transactionid, date, description, userid)` *5 billion records expected. Nearly 50K transactions per user is expected.*

`transaction_table` stores transactions done by users. This table rarely have any `UPDATE` or `DELETE` operations. There are significant `SELECT` and `INSERT` operations, but all are on the basis of `userid`. So, either I am inserting a user's transaction into the table or I am returning the transactions made by a particular user.

Does partitioning `transaction_table` make sense?

This is because, there will be 100K partition tables, each for 1 user. Is this good in any sense?

What other options do I have, to make `INSERT` and `SELECT` operations fast on `transaction_table`?

Comment: What queries are you expecting on transaction_table? Partitioning by userid makes sense if you need to retrieve ALL transactions for a specific user. For queries like "100 latest transactions of a user" an index (userid,date) should suffice.

Comment: I am expecting queries like -- (1). 'top X(say 100) transactions of a user'. (2) 'next X transactions of a user' (3) 'all transactions from 1-JAN-2015 to 1-MAY-2015 of a user' etc

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql does not recommend to create [many partitions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-CAVEATS):

> All constraints on all partitions of the master table are examined
>   during constraint exclusion, so large numbers of partitions are likely
>   to increase query planning time considerably. Partitioning using these
>   techniques will work well with up to perhaps a hundred partitions;
>   don't try to use many thousands of partitions.

On my opinion partitions created by `date` (monthly, for instance) could be much better.

Another option is to create partitions by `userid%100` but not per every user.

Comment: Partitions on the basis of date is not what I wanted to go in the first place, this is because I have queries that say 'return me last 100 transactions made by a particular user'.  Anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: It's ok if you have index by `(userid, date)` on every partition.

Comment: thanks Stas. But don't you think performance of inserts will drop significantly if I index by (userid,date).

Comment: No, I'm sure. I have partitioned table with about 20 million records per each partition (partitions are being created every month). Postgres works with it easily (there are select, insert and update operations).